# How to keep raspberrypi running on temporary voltage drop

Tags: raspbian

I have Raspberrypi 3B+ powered by a powerbank module (powerbank module + lipo cell as to have uninterrupted power supply) to power it. But when I put powerbank module to AC mains (i.e to charge lipo cell) raspberrypi suddenly get switched off and again boots (due to voltage change). How to prevent this switching off of raspberrypi ?

Comment: Obviously if the voltage drops it is not an  "uninterrupted power supply"

Comment: yeah I know :) But i used it thinking that it will act as uninterrupted power supply and its is not doing so in actual. so how can I make it to do so ?? should I add a capacitor or something else ?

Comment: A large capacitor may work.  It depends on the length of the power interruption.